# Android action bar get position of the menu item

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use Sherlock action bar in my app and I would like to find a position of the menu items. Is it possible? I want to support Android version >= 2.2. I need that position to show a tooltip above the icon of that menu item.

Comment: Tooltips are not usually used in Android, as tooltips imply the existence of a mouse or similar sort of pointing device, which most Android users are not using.

Comment: Also I would like to show that tooltip automatically only when the app is first launched to show user how to use navigation.